# No sound in headphones

Tags: audio

[image: Screenshot if I plug my headphones in jack]

I have tried various suggestions, nothing seems to work. 
The left is the pulseaudiomanager and right is audio settings.

Also if I insert my headphone in another jack, I am still not getting sound. But now in audio settings instead of line out it changes to headphone.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also. Running

```
alsactl restore
```

fixed it for me, as suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/a/859931/405972